# How to use driver initialize code from a separate class and use it in different class of same package and different package

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, driver

Stuck with making a separate class for the driver (capabilities, allowing notification, an opening web browser) within one separate class and using it is a different class of the same package and a different package

Need to fetch it on different classes

Code:

```
public class Permission {
    
    public static ChromeDriver accesspermission() {
        
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

        HashMap < String, Integer > conentSettings = new HashMap < String, Integer > ();
        HashMap < String, Object > profile = new HashMap < String, Object > ();
        HashMap < String, Object > prefs = new HashMap < String, Object > ();

        conentSettings.put("notifications", 1);
        conentSettings.put("geolocation", 1);
        conentSettings.put("media_stream", 1);

        profile.put("managed_default_content_settings", conentSettings);
        prefs.put("profile", profile);
        options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
        caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();

        driver.get("URL");
        
     }
        return driver;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us some of your code? Yet your question sounds very general.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```java
public class MyDriverStuff {

  WebDriver driver = null;

  public static WebDriver getDriver(){
    if(driver == null){
      // configure and create your driver here
      driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
    return driver;
  }


  public static void terminateDriver(){
    driver.quit();
    driver = null;
  }
}
```

**Disclaimer 1** - This is the most simple case. You need to add different posible exception cases handling.

**Disclaimer 2** - I didn't use IDE to write this code so there could be sytax errors.

**Disclaimer 3** - This case won't be working for parallel execution case. You'll have to read about `ThreadLocal` class to add multithreading support.